# How do I enable java script on Tor?

Tags: security

> How do I enable Java Script in Tor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tor Browser Bundle ship with JavaScript enabled?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/2/why-does-tor-browser-bundle-ship-with-javascript-enabled)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As the image shows click the S icon and choose your option.
Temporarily works since you don't reload the page.
Globally is for all website forever.